# phpmyadmin export table fails

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am currently running phpMyAdmin 4.7.1 against a mySQL 5.6.16 database on my Mac (El Capitan).  Everything worked well, but in order to upgrade my test Moodle database, I had to upgrade my PHP installation from 5.5.38 to 5.6.30, which I did using the excellent installation instructions here (https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/?s=El+Capitan+php).  HOWEVER, as soon as I did so, my phpMyAdmin began behaving oddly.  I can still log in, list table structure and browse contents, but then I run into problems.

ONE: When phpMyAdmin lists contents of a table, the select * from  SQL is shown in the window at the top of the page.  If I "refresh" this -- i.e., running SQL which phpMyAdmin successfully just ran, the window hangs with a message that it is trying to contact my Mac server (by name), then goes blank.

TWO: If I try to export table contents using the phpMyAdmin option, the window also hangs with the contact message, then goes blank.

There are no messages in /var/log/apache2/error_log, in /var/log/mysql/mysqld.error, or in /var/log/php/php_error.log.  There are no messages in the system.log, so I am stuck without a clue as to the issue.

Replacing PHP 5.5.38 as my PHP engine makes phpMyAdmin work (but I can't use this version going forward because it doesn't work with other software I need to develop).

I have compared the php.ini files and extension files as much as possible, but I cannot find where the pertinent lie, other than that I am using a stricter developer version of PHP 5.6.30 than I was for PHP 5.5.38. Infrequently, the export *will* work -- so I must have a permissions issue or a resource issue in my environment.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: dont consider phpmyadmin as a blocker . if mysql is working use any other tool like toad or workbench or heidisql etc and move on . btw phpmyadmin is not great either . So what is the real issue here ?https://www.sequelpro.com/

Comment: Since you mention you use phpMyAdmin 7.4.1,  did you try to update it to 4.7.2?

Comment: The real issue is the PHP configuration. i know how to dump data outside of phpMyAdmin. PHP functions related to mysqli that were working in PHP 5.5.38 are now failing in PHP 5.6.30. The phpMyAdmin export is the most obvious, but I am also seeing failures when running PHP webpages that attempt to update my database (outside of phpMyAdmin). At least once, even that worked, but failed on reboot and every since. I suspect that I am looking at either a resource or permissions issue.  Any ideas where PHP and/or mysql write temporary files on the Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Try to export the specific tables, and not the entire database at one go, or just use [mysql workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

Comment: This isn't actually the issue; I know how to export tables with mysql.  The real problem is that my PHP environment is somehow missing a key configuration component that makes exporting tables or updating tables with anything that uses PHP a problem. The PHPmyAdmin issue is one expression of this, but exports and updates to mysql also fail when run from website pages (the exact same code works perfectly on a LINUX environment).

Answer (score 0):

then try and install another php with the phpmyadmin server.. do backup your database you can get that from C:\xampp\mysql\data for windows user.

Comment: I actually still have PHP 5.5.38 and it works with PHPMyAdmin.  Please note that the issue is NOT getting PHPMyAdmin to work.  It is getting PHP 5.6.30 to work.  The PHPMyAdmin issue is only one place where the problem arises.  I cannot update/insert into my mySQL database using my old PHP webpages, either, except that once every 30 times or so, things work.  I was hoping the PHPMyAdmin manifestation would give people some idea of what to look for in the PHP environment. From my web pages, the insert simply fails to happen.  There are no error messages from the DB.

Comment: I never resolved this with the PHP I had installed using coolest guide; I eventually cleared it out, rolled my /usr/local back to before the install (thank heaven for Time Machine!) and installed using the instructions from Homebrew.  Not sure what I did wrong originally, but the Homebrew installations worked perfectly once I got Apache reconfigured.